# How to use Query functions to count values from rows?

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet, flatten

I would like to ask help to use Query functions to count values from rows?
I knew how to use =COUNTA() function to generate same results. Since my data is huge, I prefer to use Query function to keep my data flexible. Thank you for helping.

[image]

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dYrf4b1G7UouSY4XczqAClK3PhFWUkMVHJDftBRS65c/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(FLATTEN(IF(B2:F10="",,A2:A10)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) where Col1 is not null group by Col1 label count(Col1)''"))
```

[image]